# Rails: dynamic passing of value to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic

Not sure if I'm asking this question properly, but here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Select an event from a dropdown list (I know how to do this)
2. Passing that event ID to another part of the code in the form.

For example:

```
<%= form_for(@event_location) do |f| %>
  <%= select("event_location", :event_id, events_names_ids_hash, { :include_blank => true }) %>
```

Then pass the selected event_id to another part of the same form

## Amending Question

How do I capture the value of :event_id, PRIOR to submitting the form

Comment: your could use javascript to do this. If u wish to do it using javascript let me know

Comment: How do I do this through javascript?

Comment: Once the user selects a event in the browser you want the selected event id in some other part of your page right ?

Comment: I want to pass it to a function, and use the output of that function to fill a text field in the form

Comment: If its a function in ruby then you have to make a call to the server and do stuff. If you could do that calculation in javascript i will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use this. Exact code might now work you need to make small modification but this is the concept using java script.
    <%= form_for(@event_location) do |f| %>
     <%= select("event_location", :event_id, events_names_ids_hash, :onchange =>"javascriptFunction()", { :include_blank => true }) %>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function requestUrl()
  {
   var e = document.getElementById("event_id");
  var selectedId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   computedValue= "your calculation in javascript"
   document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML=computedValue;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know javascript. Would I be able to do something like this in the view: var e= document.getElementById("event_id"); return e and if so, how i call this function in my view?

Comment: Bro you need to learn a bit of javascript when your into web development. Javascript is client side scripting.Here is a [tutorial](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp) .

Comment: Bro, my question was about the proper syntax for calling javascript inside a rails view. I will mark this as answered and re-ask the question

Comment: ":onchange =>"javascriptFunction() " in my answer is one of the right ways to call a javascript function, there may be others I am just aware of one.